# "[]" vs ”array()” in Symfony2 projects

Tags: php, symfony

I designed a Symfony2-based website which I deployed successfully online on GoDaddy server and everything was working fine.

After I edited my website and uploaded everything on server I noticed an error saying something relating to a syntax error due to the occurrence of '[' in line 47 of MappingDriverChain.php file (please check out the attached image).

[image]

The consequence was the absence of the background styling all the routes, for instance http://yplushy.com/diapers. I was able to resolve the issue in /mothers_space by replacing

> private $drivers = [];

with

> private $drivers = array();

And clearing the cache. I had to repeat this in

> webroot / yplushy / vendor / doctrine / common / lib / Doctrine / Common / Persistence / Mapping / Driver / SymfonyFileLocator.php

But as you can see I still have this issue with /diapers, and the problem is I don't know where in my code there is still the occurrence of "[]" instead of "array()".

Please note that in my local environment I don't have this issue.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: This depends of PHP version (5.4 allow this [] instead of array()). Check in your hosting- can u modify PHP version to newest one... I am sure they have that option for upgrade.

Comment: You might want to read the requirements for symfony.

Comment: You're on a dangerously insecure unsupported version of PHP. Upgrade ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is the way you can define an array in PHP 5.4+

But, if you are using PHP 5.3 or lower, you have to use `array()`

Have a look at **Example #1** on http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Nope.  S2 needs only needs 5.3.  S3 needs 5.5.

Comment: @Cerad, you are right.